# How to deselect the selected item when we click on another item in the listview in android

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview in my app and want to set a background color for each item that is selected and at same time i want to move to another activity. Then if I select another item in the list the one that was selected before should be deselected. I'm not getting the deselection when another item is clicked.

Comment: adding some code will improve your post....

Comment: most general solution would be, u again reinitialize the previous list item by default.

Answer (score 2):

```
             <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgfavoriteactive"
        android:layout_width="35dip"
        android:layout_height="35dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:src="@drawable/favorite" />


        favorite.xml set in drawable folder

       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
          <item android:state_selected="true"
              android:drawable="@drawable/favoriteactive"/>
          <item android:state_selected="false"
              android:drawable="@drawable/favoriteinactive"/>
        </selector>





        img_nfl_favoriteactive.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                  for (int i = 0; i < listview.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    listview.getChildAt(i)
                            .findViewById(R.id.imgfavoriteactive)
                            .setSelected(false);

                }

                    img_nfl_favoriteactive.setSelected(true);
            }
        });
```